# Upgrading to Bugzilla 5.0

Tags: mysql, perl, bugzilla

While setting up Bugzilla 5.0, running ./checksetup.pl I ran into this beauty:

```
Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.
Fixing file permissions...
Adding foreign key: test_case_components.component_id ->
components.id...
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Cannot add foreign key constraint [for Statement "ALTER TABLE test_case_components ADD 
 CONSTRAINT fk_test_case_components_component_id_components_id FOREIGN KEY (component_id)
 REFERENCES components(id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE"] at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 642.
Bugzilla::DB::bz_add_fks(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x6c66e10), "test_case_components", HASH(0x61a5f30), HASH(0xa283c48)) called at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 546
Bugzilla::DB::bz_setup_foreign_keys(Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x6c66e10)) called at Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm line 745
Bugzilla::Install::DB::update_table_definitions(HASH(0x1522580)) called at ./checksetup.pl line 172
```

Is it due to my database setup? Has anyone else ran into this? If so do you have a patch that worked for you?

Comment: The test_case_components table is part of Testopia. At this time Testopia is not compatible with Bugzilla 5. There is work going on to make it so. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Bugzilla/Testopia

Answer (score 1):

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923865 (which an internet search engine should hopefully bring up).

Comment: Please add some content from the link.